# replacing a scene from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am having a problem which i doubt that related to cocos2d, but i use cocos.

there are some scenes in our app , that we can replace them with `relpaceScene` -cocos2d method.

NOW, there is another new class, that is not a view and nothing else but do that:  get notified from the notification center, and then replace the current scene that on screen.

when i do that,replace the scene, the NSLog of that scene is being called, BUT, all the sprites in that scene are not displayed ,and i see a white screen.

it seems that some how this class is released, or something, or that i cant replace the scene from this class from some reason.

this problem is very strange and i hope you have ANY clue .

code to replace scene :(that works from other scenes,but not from that class)

```
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[BasicSceneWithCat scene] setBackgroundSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bedroom&cat_bg.png"] withType:@"bedroom"]];
```

class and unction being called,but the `[self addChild:sprite];` is not happen.

thanks ./

Answer (score 0):

I can't see directly where your problem is byt the line of code you use is unusual in itself:

Try something along the lines of the example I give. (You will need to change it to suit your case accordingly)

```
BasicSceneWithCat *scene = [BasicSceneWithCat scene];
[scene setBackgroundSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bedroom&cat_bg.png"]];
[scene setType:@"bedroom"];

[[CCDirection sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what you say seems logic,because then i save the new scene BUT, IN cocos2d, if you in sceneA and want to move to sceneB you dont have to do the allocation and instance things, you just replaceScene and it takes care of that. i am sure about that because i do transition between scene with that. the question is, why when using this from another class that is not a scene, its not working.

Comment: In cocos2d you definitely DO have to have an allocated and instantiated scene before you can transition to it. Otherwise how would the CCDirector know which piece of memory to access and treat as a CCScene? If you claim that the piece of code you've posted is working, I can't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your problem is in the wrong usage of

```
replaceScene:
```

method. You must pass a CCScene object in this method as argument. But you pass there the result of your

```
setBackgroundSprite:withType:
```

method. And I think, it does not return anything.

Comment: first , it return,because IT OPENS the new scene and log it(as i said) , second, when i use this exact line, EXACT, from a scene that is now one screen, it works great. so it seems that it RETURN what it needs, because transition from sceneA to B works, but from class to B does not . any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just read your question. I am not pretty sure what you want to do.. But you can try one thing.. In case of notifications generally you have delegate methods implemented in a scene/layer class.So instead of calling from that class.. Try to call method in the scene/layer class... or you can call a method from your class like...

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] callMethodToReplaceScene];
```

and in this method replaceScene normally as you do.

Comment: i did what you just said,i have created the callMethodToReplaceScene  AND , it gives me warning on your line that CCScene may not respond to callMethodToReplaceScene, why is that ? i have that method. this whole thing is so strnage ,and i really want to understand want went wrong here

Comment: to avoid warnings you should declare this method first. or it must be implemented before method, that calls it

Comment: This warning can be removed by adding a simple cast .. like

`[(YourScene *)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] callMethodToReplaceScene];`

This YourScene is name of the class that has your method.. Just check if it works fine.. :)